# Parsing JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON string in java to have the individual value printed separately. But while making the program run I get the following error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
       at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:7)
       at ShowActivity.main(ShowActivity.java:29)
```

My Class looks like-

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ShowActivity {
   private final static String  jString = "{" 
   + "    \"geodata\": [" 
   + "        {" 
   + "                \"id\": \"1\"," 
   + "                \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","                  
   + "                \"gender\" : \"female\"," 
   + "                \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\"," 
   + "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""            
   + "                }" 
   + "        }," 
   + "        {" 
   + "                \"id\": \"2\"," 
   + "                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","          
   + "                \"gender\" : \"male\"," 
   + "                \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\"," 
   + "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""            
   + "                }" 
   + "        }" 
   + "    ]" 
   + "}"; 
   private static JSONObject jObject = null;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
       jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
       JSONObject geoObject = jObject.getJSONObject("geodata");

       String geoId = geoObject.getString("id");
           System.out.println(geoId);

       String name = geoObject.getString("name");
       System.out.println(name);

       String gender=geoObject.getString("gender");
       System.out.println(gender);

       String lat=geoObject.getString("latitude");
       System.out.println(lat);

       String longit =geoObject.getString("longitude");
       System.out.println(longit);                   
   }
}
```

Let me know what is it I am missing, or the reason why I do get that error everytime I run the application. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: `android.jar` only contains stubs to compile against. To run, you need the full library.

Comment: Yes I imported `android.jar` in my project.. Can you point me from where I can download the full library?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java#comment15799748_11874919).
You need to include the full [org.json library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) when running as *android.jar* only contains stubs to compile against.

In addition, you must remove the two instances of extra `}` in your JSON data following `longitude`.

```
   private final static String JSON_DATA =
     "{" 
   + "  \"geodata\": [" 
   + "    {" 
   + "      \"id\": \"1\"," 
   + "      \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","                  
   + "      \"gender\" : \"female\"," 
   + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\"," 
   + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""
   + "    }," 
   + "    {" 
   + "      \"id\": \"2\"," 
   + "      \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","          
   + "      \"gender\" : \"male\"," 
   + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\"," 
   + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""
   + "    }" 
   + "  ]" 
   + "}";
```

Apart from that, `geodata` is in fact not a `JSONObject` but a `JSONArray`.

Here is the fully working and tested corrected code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ShowActivity {


  private final static String JSON_DATA =
     "{" 
   + "  \"geodata\": [" 
   + "    {" 
   + "      \"id\": \"1\"," 
   + "      \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","                  
   + "      \"gender\" : \"female\"," 
   + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\"," 
   + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""
   + "    }," 
   + "    {" 
   + "      \"id\": \"2\"," 
   + "      \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","          
   + "      \"gender\" : \"male\"," 
   + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\"," 
   + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""
   + "    }" 
   + "  ]" 
   + "}"; 

  public static void main(final String[] argv) throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
    final JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONArray("geodata");
    final int n = geodata.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      final JSONObject person = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println(person.getInt("id"));
      System.out.println(person.getString("name"));
      System.out.println(person.getString("gender"));
      System.out.println(person.getDouble("latitude"));
      System.out.println(person.getDouble("longitude"));
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
C:\dev\scrap>java -cp json.jar;. ShowActivity
1
Julie Sherman
female
37.33774833333334
-121.88670166666667
2
Johnny Depp
male
37.336453
-121.884985
```

Comment: Thanks veer. I opened that link but I couldn't find the jar file to download. Can you point me to exact location from where I can download it.

Comment: @Nevzz03 try [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar).

Comment: I did as per your suggestion. I downloaded the jar also, imported into our project too. And when I ran my project, I got exception as- `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["geodata"] is not a JSONObject.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:596)
 at com.niharika.testing.JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:31)
` Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: @Nevzz03 I have posted fully working code now. Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot veer. Really appreciate all your help!!

Comment: @Nevzz03 no problem dude! Glad I could help :-) Note you won't need the *json.jar* when deploying via Android.

Comment: The link to org.json is dead. However, The example also works with [JSON-Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). I only had to move the files, according to the referred package, to a newly created folder `org/json/`.

Answer (score 6):

To convert your **JSON string to hashmap** you can make use of this :

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>(Utility.jsonToMap(response)) ;
```

**Use this class :)** (handles even lists , nested lists and json)

```
public class Utility {

    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(Object json) throws JSONException {

        if(json instanceof JSONObject)
            return _jsonToMap_((JSONObject)json) ;

        else if (json instanceof String)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)json) ;
            return _jsonToMap_(jsonObject) ;
        }
        return null ;
    }


   private static Map<String, Object> _jsonToMap_(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }


    private static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }


    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thats very useful piece of code, thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 4):

credit to [this blog](https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/)
This answer may help someone whose requirements are different.

This is your Json string

```
 {
"pageNumber":20,
"pageTitle":"example page title",
"pageInfo": {
        "pageName": "Homepage",
        "logo": "https://www.example.com/logo.jpg"
},
"posts": [
        {
            "post_id": "0123456789",
            "actor_id": "1001",
            "author_name": "Jane Doe",
            "post_title": "How to parse JSON in Java",
            "comments": [],
            "time_of_post": "1234567890"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is how to read it

```
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class ParseJSON {
 static String json = "...";
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    String pageTitle = obj.getString("pageTitle");
    String pageNumber= obj.getInt("pageNumber");
    String pageName =      obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

    System.out.println(pageNumber);
    System.out.println(pageTitle );
    System.out.println(pageName);

    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
        System.out.println(post_id);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like for both of your objects (inside the array), you have an extra closing brace after "Longitude".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly there is an extra `}` after every `array object`.

Secondly "geodata" is a `JSONArray`. So instead of `JSONObject geoObject = jObject.getJSONObject("geodata");` you have to get it as `JSONArray geoObject = jObject.getJSONArray("geodata");`

Once you have the `JSONArray` you can fetch each entry in the `JSONArray` using `geoObject.get(<index>)`.

I am using `org.codehaus.jettison.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example of one Object, For your case you have to use JSONArray.

```
public static final String JSON_STRING="{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"Sachin\",\"salary\":56000}}";  
try{  
   JSONObject emp=(new JSONObject(JSON_STRING)).getJSONObject("employee");  
   String empname=emp.getString("name");  
   int empsalary=emp.getInt("salary");  

   String str="Employee Name:"+empname+"\n"+"Employee Salary:"+empsalary;  
   textView1.setText(str);  

}catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
   //Do when JSON has problem.
}
```

I don't have time but tried to give an idea. If you still can't do it, then  I will help.

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra "**}**" in each object,
you may write the json string like this:

```
public class ShowActivity {   
    private final static String  jString = "{" 
    + "    \"geodata\": [" 
    + "        {" 
    + "                \"id\": \"1\"," 
    + "                \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","                  
    + "                \"gender\" : \"female\"," 
    + "                \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\"," 
    + "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""            
    + "                }" 
    + "        }," 
    + "        {" 
    + "                \"id\": \"2\"," 
    + "                \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","          
    + "                \"gender\" : \"male\"," 
    + "                \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\"," 
    + "                \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""            
    + "                }" 
    + "        }" 
    + "    ]" 
    + "}"; 
}
```

Comment: @Nevzz03 you may use [link](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)flexjson java lib to create you json object instead.