# Android - java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub exception while parsing String into JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` exception when I try to parse `String` to `org.json.JSONObject`. My **Android** API version is **19**.

Here is my `String` to be parsed:

```
{
    "url": "http://www.google.com",
    "cookie": "012121",
    "filename": "Google"
}


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str); // getting exception at this line
String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
```

Comment: Try this.. link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java

Comment: Are you getting this error on device/emulator or on your environment (tests)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875002/2337837

Comment: thanks everyone for their comments. I was running tests @endriu_l.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is probably  because you are using android-provided json implementation and you are not running it on an android device or emulator.

Depending on your real need you can either :

- run it on a device or emulator
- use another json library instead of the one embedded in android
- use roboelectric to run your test (if it's a test) without an emulator : http://robolectric.org/

Comment: Also, the problem can be in classpath order for regular JUnit tests. I faced with such order issue and was managed to solve it with this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507579/902217

Comment: How do I run the unit tests on a real device?