# How to configure the order of libraries in the classpath for Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, classpath, build.gradle

I would like to change the order of libraries in the classpath for Android Studio. I am trying to **run unit tests** with JUnit 4 from **within the IDE**. This works following the [instruction in these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/tobiaspreuss/how-to-setup-unit-testing-in-android-studio).

I wonder if it is possible to **configure the order of the libraries** - other then suggested in the slides - via the *Run Configuration* of Android Studio?

The first attempt was to change the order of dependencies in the *Project Structure* dialog in the *Dependency* tab of the project module as show in the screenshot.

[image: Project Structure]

The second guess was to include the classpath configuration in the `build.gradle` file. There are a couple of **vague** ideas about this:

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath = file("foo.jar") + sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
```

...

```
sourceSets.test.compileClasspath = configurations.robo + sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath = configurations.robo + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
```

- Sources: [[[1](http://www.slideshare.net/tobiaspreuss/how-to-setup-unit-testing-in-android-studio)](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_control_the_order_of_compiletime_classpaths#reply_7726876)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7281162/356895)]

Comment: You can solve it by gradle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38743046/715269

Answer (score 7):

I use the following task to make sure that the SDK dependency is listed last:

```
task pushDownJdkDependency {
    def imlFile = file("ui.iml")
    doLast {
        try {
            def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(imlFile)
            def jdkNode = parsedXml.component[1].orderEntry.find { it.'@type' == 'jdk' }

            parsedXml.component[1].remove(jdkNode)
            new Node(parsedXml.component[1], 'orderEntry', ['type': 'jdk', 'jdkName': "Android API 18 Platform", 'jdkType': 'Android SDK'])
            def writer = new StringWriter()
            new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(parsedXml)
            imlFile.text = writer.toString()

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // nop, iml not found
        }
    }
}
```

make sure you use the correct SDK identifier. Then hook the task into the build process:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(pushDownJdkDependency)
}
```

Other than that, add the task to your run configuration. Unfortunately I cannot post images due to lack of reputation.

Comment: If you upload the images somewhere I am happy to edit your post and include them for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. It didn't work for me until I removed the `doLast` part... I guess doing it last was too late for some reason?

Comment: Pitty that we have to resolve to something like that with android studio :/ But thx a lot for this solution, might come in handy!

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the project `.iml` file to have the JDK as the last entry like the following:

```
    <orderEntry type="library" 
                exported="" 
                scope="TEST" 
                name="wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6" 
                level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" 
                exported="" 
                scope="TEST" 
                name="xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2" 
                level="project" />
    <!-- make sure this is the last orderEntry -->
    <orderEntry type="jdk" 
                jdkName="Android API 19 Platform" 
                jdkType="Android SDK" /> 
  </component>
</module>
```

For a full working example see Robolectric's **[deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle)** sample.

Comment: But: *"Android Studio aggressively re-writes your dependencies list (your .iml file) and subverts the technique used above to get the Android SDK to the bottom of the classpath. You will get the dreaded Stub! exception every time you re-open the project (and possibly more often)."* - [Source](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there seems to be no good work around for android studio :(. I guess its why they are recommending Intellij for now.

Comment: One could write a script similar to the one in the slides mention in my question which then hooks into the build process and updates the `.iml` at the right time.