# Android Studio: How do I include a Java Module in an Android Module?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In Android studio I have an Android module, let's call it MyAndroid.  I also have a Java module (not a standalone JAR, but a full Java project within a module), let's call it MyJava.

I want MyAndroid to use MyJava as a project dependency.  I have tried using the standard project compilation:

`compile project(':myjava')`

MyAndroid compiles, and I even see the myjava.jar under "External Libraries" but the MyAndroid source code cannot see any of the Classes within the MyJava source code.  It's as if MyJava isn't linked at all.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there an extra detail when depending upon Java modules instead of other Android modules?

---

**EDIT**
I opened up the MyAndroid.iml file to see if anything looked obviously broken.  I noticed that there was no  for MyJava.  I manually added:

`<orderEntry type="module" module-name="myjava" exported="" />`

This seems to have solved the source code resolution issue.  But I think this manual change will disappear the moment I run another Gradle sync.  Any idea why this  wasn't present and how I can tell Gradle to do this?

---

**EDIT #2**
I still don't know why the Java module won't link correctly to MyAndroid, but I gave up and added a Gradle task that forces the `<orderEntry>` node into the IML file:

I adapted the code example in this answer to suite my needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24138659/3724038

Comment: Make sure your java module is registered in settings.gradle of your application

Comment: @avinash Confirmed.  The java module appears in settings.gradle.

Comment: Try to add your module from the Project Structure option

Comment: @avinash I tried adding the module to the Project Structure dependency for MyAndroid.  It still isn't working.  The only answer so far is to add the <orderEntry> to the IML file.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3 and this problem disappeared, so it looks like it was an IDE bug.