# Get element from JSON file using getJSONArray() and getJSONObject() in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, element

I would like to **walk through the json file below and save the part after "coordinates".**

The json file:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {},"geometry": {"type": "LineString","coordinates": [[4.354282,52.032195],[4.354087,52.032462],[4.353783,52.032962],[4.353579,52.033437],[4.353333,52.034151],[4.352991,52.03545],[4.352517,52.037002],[4.352442,52.037352],[4.352368,52.0378],[4.352336,52.038238],[4.352331,52.039962],[4.352346,52.040706]
    ]
  }
}
```

]
}

I've seen code using getJSONArray() and getJSONObject() [here](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java). This information helped me to select (in my case) the "geometry" tree.

My code so far (test2.geojson is the json file mentioned above):

```
        String output = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths
                .get("C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\test2.geojson")));

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);

        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("features");
        System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

However, this only rearranges the file and appends the first part to the end of the file.

```
[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[4.354282,52.032195],[4.354087,52.032462],[4.353783,52.032962],[4.353579,52.033437],[4.353333,52.034151],[4.352991,52.03545],[4.352517,52.037002],[4.352442,52.037352],[4.352368,52.0378],[4.352336,52.038238],[4.352331,52.039962],[4.352346,52.040706]],"type":"LineString"},"type":"Feature","properties":{}}]
```

Any solutions to get the desired output of:

```
[[4.354282,52.032195],[4.354087,52.032462],[4.353783,52.032962],[4.353579,52.033437],[4.353333,52.034151],[4.352991,52.03545],[4.352517,52.037002],[4.352442,52.037352],[4.352368,52.0378],[4.352336,52.038238],[4.352331,52.039962],[4.352346,52.040706]
    ]
  }
}
```

]
}

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "geometry" is a json object {}, "coordinates" is a json array [],

You should be doing

```
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("features");
JSONArray resultArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject[0].getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONArray("coordinates")
```

Comment: jsonArray.getJSONObject("geometry") gives the following error.


The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String).

I'm using the org.json library.

Comment: get the first object from jsonArray first, then apply my code

Comment: Thanks for helping. jsonArray.getJSONArray[0] is throwing:     getJSONArray cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Are you also using org.json library? Just to be sure.

Comment: @Camelaria ops, you should be using jsonArray.getJSONObject(0) ....instead of jsonArray.getJSONArray(0)...my bad but hey you can spot this easily too~

Comment: Very true, but I thought that it could only be accessed by an getJSONArray(). Thank you, this generated the output I wanted! :)