# How can I break this Json string in android?

Tags: android, json

My JSON string is :[["Canada", 3], ["SriLanka", 6], ["China", 5], ["UK", 4]]

Comment: Please help me to get country name from the above string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  JSONArray ja = new JSONArray("[['Canada', 3], ['SriLanka', 6], ['China', 5], ['UK', 4]]");
  for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
    JSONArray ja1 = ja.getJSONArray(i);
    System.out.println("Country Name = "+ja1.get(0));
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard for JSON. You have to build it this way:

```
[{"country":"Canada", "x":3}, {"country":"SriLanka", "x":6}, {"country":"China", "x":5}...]
```

Brackets mean JSONArray

Anyway, if want to split a String.. use Java Basics... It's not an Android issue.

Split by regex and patterns, using split String basic method, or dealing them as a JSONArray..

You can find a lot of information in other posts.

PS: Too long to be a comment.

I hope I would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
     JSONArray array1=array.getJSONArray(i);
     for(int j=0;j<array1.length();j++){
      System.out.print(array1.getString(0));
      System.out.print(array1.getInt(1));
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct `JSON` format should be as follows,

> [{'name':'Canada', 'value':'3'}, {'name':'SriLanka', 'value':'6'},
>   {'name': 'China', 'value':'5'}]

Then you can do,

```
List<Country> list2 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,  Country.class));
```

where

Country is,

```
public class Country {
   private int value;
   private String name;
   //getters and setters
}
```