# How to use regular expression

Tags: java, regex

The original string looks like:

```
 [[{"v":new Date(2013, 2, 16, 8, 0),"f":"March 2013"},null,null,95,null,null,true],
 [{"v":new Date(2013, 3, 15, 20, 0),"f":"April 2013"},null,null,97,null,null,true]],
 "showHeadlines" ...
```

You can see, there are a sequence of data which are included in a pair of "[ ]", and I want to extract the number which stay in "null, null, ..., null, null" combo. And my regular expression is:

```
  String reg = "null/,([0-9]*)/,null";
```

But it does not work. Could you help me to modify it? Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Are these JSON Strings?

Comment: This looks like JSON

Comment: Original poster, this looks like JSON -- don't parse with regex. Use a JSON  parser.

Comment: It is from a <script> segment which is included in a html file I download from a website.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks! Could you give me a related link?

Comment: [Java parsing JSON Strings](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+parsing+json+string+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Got it! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score -2):

As **HovercraftFullOfEels** pointed out in the comments already, parsing JSON using RegEx is not recommended ([reasoning here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751940/5529417)). Using a [JSON Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875002/5529417) is the way to go.