# Conver spring String object to iteratable json object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am receiving a string object in my spring controller class as follows

```
{'Gyr-x':10.11,'Gyr-y':9.66,'Gyr-z':10.93,'Temparature':30,'Pressure':101,'Humidity':15,'deviceId':1},{'Gyr-x':10.11,'Gyr-y':9.66,'Gyr-z':10.93,'Temparature':30,'Pressure':101,'Humidity':15,'deviceId':1}
```

Which is technically 2 arrays.

I want to convert this string object into JSON and do iteration on this two arrays, to fetch keys of each array. i do not wish to map this to any POJO classes as Jackson and Gson do.

Comment: They are not technically 2 arrays, they are two objects / dicts / maps. Please add some code and what you've already tried.

Comment: Btw. the input is not valid json: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this: 
[Parsing JSON string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java)

This only works, if your JSON is valid! So for your example, you have to split the string into two separate strings.

The you have something like a `Map` and you can iterate over the items like this:
[How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)