# get particular value from json object

Tags: json

```
{
"CustomerDetails": [
    {
        "AccountName": "test",
        "DnBNumber": 12342314
    }
]
```

}

I want to get value from this json object.

I tried below but not working.

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("AccountName").toString();
```

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874919/parsing-json-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON you put, there are a *JsonObject* that contains a *JsonArray*, that contains two *String*, so..

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON);
final JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("CustomerDetails");

for (int i = 0; i < geodata.length(); ++i) {
  final JSONObject detail = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
  System.out.println(detail.getString("AccountName"));
  System.out.println(detail.getString("DnBNumber"));
}
```